# return a php file content using .ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

so I have a file that will get `$_GET['id']` from an ajax request 
here is a part of the php file:

```
include "system/dbconnect.php";
// Script Bin Plugin
$id = $_GET['id']; 

 $hresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options
 WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo '<ul class="ul"> more content goes here...';
```

I edited the question to make it clearer: 
I would like to return the file's content, the html and mysql results going through a loop then rendering the widgets that contain different info from the db using ajax ...

Comment: You mean you have the name of a file and you want to output the contents of the file?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here. Do you want to print anything `echo`d by your PHP file back to the browser?

Comment: well its a file that will render 18 different divs (widgets)each div will the render different information from the db. I have a file handler.php that checks the table for active=yes widgets and then will display all of them through a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should escape variables passed via GET:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(intval($_GET['id']));
```

Then you can simply run a loop using [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
$hresult = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `options` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'"
) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<ul class="ul">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hresult)) {
    echo '<li>' . $row['value'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: For an ID, `intval()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Actually, escaping is not necessary after converting to an int since there is nothing to escape in a numeric value, ever.

Comment: True, I'm just in the habit of not trusting myself to be smart enough to make that call most of the time :)

Comment: That's why it's better not to use dynamic sql at all but use e.g. PDO with prepared statements! And when that's no an option I usually do the escaping right when I build the query - you usually don't want sql-escaped variables floating around anyway, since you might accidentally send them back to the browser; presenting ugly backslashes to the user.

Comment: I am looping through include to display each file based on the settings its working fine thank you guys. and thanks for the mysql_real_escape_string very useful